# How does Quick Scoping or "Feather" Scoping work in Modern Warfare 3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I know some may cry "foul" or "cheating" but I'm really fascinated by the people who seem to be amazing marksman in the Modern Warfare series via a quick scope kill.

Can anyone detail out the mechanics of quick scoping for MW3?

I'm on xbox 360.

Answer (score 6):

The key to QS is to make sure before you take your shot - you are completely stationary. Too many people who try quickscoping are still moving when they take their shot and this results in about a 1:4 shot-to-kill ratio ... it's frustrating as I used to fire while still moving and even though you are lined up and it is dead on them.  I was sometimes too keen to get that shot off. When you are still moving it seems as though the bullet passes straight through them, when in fact it actually hasn't gone where you intended it to go.

Secondly try to shoot from cover at first. Get into the habit of ducking and going prone, then standing - taking your shot and dropping as you shoot. This is known as a drop shot.

When you get good - you can start to drag scope, which is basically where you go to scope in and your crosshairs aren't lined up with the enemy - you have to VERY QUICKLY drag the scope right or left and time the shot and fire when crosshairs are over your opponent.

Once you have mastered the basics - you can look at 360's, stalls and no-scopes.

Remember, line up target, stop, shoot.  You want to consider a sensitivity of something between 6 and 10. I play on 9, but worked up from 5. 10 i find is just a bit too erratic for anything other than a run and gun.

Really you just have to practice, there is no shortcut to no-scoping.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for mentioning drag scoping. Wherever I see kill cams of people drag scoping it is utterly amazing to me that they were able to correct a shot by so much in less than a second

Answer (score 2):

Basically, Sniper Rifle's are extremely inaccurate while not scoping, but will instantly become extremely accurate when you scope in.

This happens extremely quickly after holding in the scope button (not sure if it's instant or just really really quick), so people will click both scope and shoot at almost the exact same time, which will make you shoot very accurately at whatever you're aiming at, so instead of trying to "noscope" someone, they'll try to "quickscope" them instead.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the "how" part and leave the "why" part out?

Comment: @Bora "people will click both scope and shoot at almost the exact same time". That's all there is to it. Can't really elaborate on that.

Answer (score 2):

I've not been able to do much quickscoping in MW3 yet, but I use to do it some in MW2. The basics are this:

First do some target practice. Find something not moving. Aim at it *without scoping* and then press the scope button(left trigger on xbox) and about a quarter of a second later shoot. Repeat until you're hitting your target. The basic thing you have to do is automatically know where the center of your TV screen is. Some people actually put a physical "dot" sticker in the center of their TV for this. I think that's taking it a bit too far though.

I haven't leveled up too far yet in MW3 so I'll include some relevant information on what the perks and proficiencies should be for quickscoping later.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like babble, too lazy to reread it but I tried to get everything in 1 go. This is how I taught my friends to quickscope but I was helping them step by step so it'll be different. I use ps3 btw.

By looking into the scope, your crosshairs get smaller until it's almost perfect due to the sniper scope. Quickscopers utilize this by shooting their gun as soon as the crosshairs reach it's most accurate point as a)the shot will be on target b)it doesnt give the enemy time to kill you as if you were trying to hardscope them. 
To learn to quickscope, get in a game by yourself. Tap the aim button repeatedly and watch your crosshairs get smaller and smaller. Try to anticipate when it's the smallest, thats usually right before you can see inside your sniper scope. When it's at the smallest, shoot. As you get better, you'll be able to learn how to walk and do that until it becomes natural.

If you are a good learner and you can pick up how to do it the hard way, I recommend playing black ops and quickscoping there. I practice quickscoping on black ops in combat training by setting the computer to veteran. Black ops quickscoping is focused on the drag-scope.

MW3 is the easiest to quickscope, then mw2 (but that has a ton of aimbots), then blackops is the hardest. You can only hit someone in black ops by drag scoping so I dont recommend doing that first.